# Hostlistener keyup event not specific to input element

Tags: angular

I have the custom directive that check for the count of character in the input field and change background colour based on the count oof character.

```
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  HostListener,
  HostBinding,
  OnChanges
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMydirective]'
})
export class MydirectiveDirective implements OnChanges {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
  @HostListener("window:keyup") ngOnChanges() {
    let count = this.el.nativeElement.value.length;
    if (count <= 25) this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = "#ff5858";
    else if (count > 25 && count < 50) this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = "#c988ff";
    else if (count >= 50) this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = "#c5ff9a";
  }
}
```

This directive is used in HTML file.

```
<textarea  [class.is-invalid] = "myForm.get('aboutU').invalid && myForm.get('aboutU').touched" class="form-control" placeholder="Atleast 25 characters" id="aboutU" rows="3" formControlName="aboutU" appMydirective></textarea>
```

The problem is when I was typing the `email` input element, this `aboutU` background colour is changing.
It's not specify to the that aboutU input element. Why?
If I'm using the `ngStyle` directive it worked like charm, but I need to figure out this issue why the other input element changing on typing in other elements.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this randomly as I thought what the use of `window` in `window:keyup` and it worked.
So change this line
`@HostListener("window:keyup") ngOnChanges()`
to `@HostListener("keyup") ngOnChanges()`
It worked.